# Telegram Bot with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I want to build a bot in Telegram with Laravel 5.3, but I have some problems...

My site is located on the computer. How can I register some easy commands (/help, /start)? When I'm writing to bot, it doesn't respond to commands :( But I can get the bot data (id, firstname and bot name). This is my ugly TelegramController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram;

class TelegramController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        $response = Telegram::getMe();
        dd($response);
    }
}
```

Please, write some examples... I do not understand what is written in the docs. Have a good day and thanks for help!

Github repository:
https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a self signed certificate and send it as a parameter through setWebHook to Telegram.

[Using self-signed certificates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed)

If you're hosting it on your computer!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can handle user commands.

1. using [self signed certificates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed)
2. using [Webhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) (recommended) Get rid of processing each request manually or setting timers

You are specifically looking for a Laravel bot so you can find the unofficial package [here](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk)

and [here](https://jqueryajaxphp.com/create-telegram-bot-api-using-laravel/) is a step by step guide for you to get started. This blog also has a series of telegram bot articles that helps set Webhook, keyboards and callbacks

If you are looking to buy cheap SSL certificates you can go for [SSLS](https://www.ssls.com/) and check out [FREE SSL](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Comment: You missed long-polling (`getUpdates` method)